# how to make the webbrowser read and use proxies one by one or line by line?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, proxies

am using webbrowser to fill out forms in an site rapidly so it keeps blocking my ip , ive used an proxy on the webbrowser that work for like 5 minutes then the site block it again + i use openFileDialog to import the proxies into a textbox then let the code below use it but it keep using just one proxy SO i want it to use another proxy from the textbox every time i click the button

```
Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
        Public dwAccessType As Integer
        Public proxy As IntPtr
        Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure
Private Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean

Private Sub RefreshIESettings(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3
    Dim s_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    s_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    s_IPI.proxy = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    s_IPI.proxyBypass = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("Global")

    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s_IPI))
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(s_IPI, intptrStruct, True)
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s_IPI))

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RefreshIESettings(textbox1.Text)
```

Comment: Half your code is outside the code section, add some spaces before the lines

Comment: You can have a txt file with all your proxies on each line, use a streamreader with streamreader.readline, that's how you can work with each proxy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a static index. It will loop back to the first strProxy when the list is exhausted.

```
Private lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadLines("proxies.txt").ToList

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static i As Integer
    If i = lines.Count Then
        i = 0
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = lines(i)
    i += 1
End Sub
```